# React router path syntax confusion

Tags: react-router

Could someone please explain why the child route is not found when the slash is applied to the child path

```
<Route path=":paramName1">
    ...
    <Route path="/:paramName2" component={Child} />
</Route>
```

Yet is successful when the slash is applied, optionally, to the parent path?

```
<Route path=":paramName1(/)">
    ...
    <Route path=":paramName2" component={Child} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're inadvertently hitting https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.3/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md#decoupling-the-ui-from-the-url.

For a simpler example, if you do

```js
<Route path="/foo" component={Parent}>
  <Route path="/bar" component={Child} />
</Route>
```

The path for `Child` will actually be `/bar`, not `/foo/bar`.

In your case, you simply want

```
<Route path="/:foo" component={Parent}>
  <Route path=":bar" component={Child} />
</Route>
```

To get `/:foo/:bar` for `Child`.